# Sort Reviews/Ratings by date on Woocommerce

Tags: plugins, page-template, woocommerce-offtopic, review

I would like to change the order the reviews are being displayed on the single product page, currently it's in Ascending order and we need it in Descending order.(Most recent to oldest) I've looked at the review.php file but it appear to not have a sort order. If you could point me in the right direction or give me an alternative solution i'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WooCommerce questions are off-topic, but since reviews are merely comments, I think we can make the case that ordering comments is still on-topic.

[`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) has a `reverse_top_level` parameter that will set the most recent comment first and then go backwards. Assuming it works like I think it should then you'd want to add this parameter to WooCommerce's `wp_list_comments()`.

Conveniently, a filter is available for the `wp_list_comments()` args that are used in the `single-product-reviews.php` template.

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
</ol>
```

So, then to filter in new args, the process of filtering is the same as usual:

```
function wpa_filter_list_comments($args){
  $args['reverse_top_level'] = true;
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', 'wpa_filter_list_comments' );
```

Comment: Do note that this is untested so your mileage may vary.

Comment: The request was dropped for sorting them DESC but I do appreciate the timely response. Although I didn't utilize your code, I am very thankful. I'll post this in the woo commerce support/suggestion area and hopefully it will implemented further down the line.

Comment: If you didn't test this then how do you know if it really answers the question? I'm not sure what you are expecting Woo to implement. If this works, then they don't need to change anything.